# How can this scroll animation be achieved in a react website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, scroll, web

I am currently building a react website and I would like to know how can this scrolling animation be achieved? 
Especially the 'paper sheet coming up' animation when you scroll down.

Website reference: [Scrolling animation](https://voltfordrive.com/drivers/)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/gilbox/react-spark-scroll does the job.

Comment: As this question is not suited for stack overflow im going to vote to close it. This type of question leads to a lot of opinion based answers, SO is better suited as a platform for users to post a question with code that has an issue. That being said, I think Pal gave you a solution though with spark scroll :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using ref as:

```
this.image.scrollIntoView({block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Note: this.image is your ref to which you want to scroll.